# Compile two different jars in maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm developing a small library and I want to compile it to two versions using maven. One version should contain the main class, the other version shouldn't contain it.

Is there a way to compile two different jar's? If yes, how?

Comment: with 2 maven projects ?

Comment: Refer to the linked question, but the bottom-line is: don't do it and create a multi-module project instead. Extract the common parts in a module, and make 2 other modules create the final JARs with a dependency on the common code.